# Diagonal entries of band matrix not colinear

Tags: math-mode, matrices

I have band matrix. Columns of if are formatted to have variable width and this results in `\ddots` aligned in an ugly way. I'm looking for a compact solution without need for manually controlling each cells size/position.

Here is a code snippet producing this matrix.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
    \mathcal{L} = \begin{bmatrix}
 -2 &-3q&   &    &      &            &      \\
    &-20&-6q&    &      &            &      \\
    &-q &-90&-10q&      &            &      \\
    &   &-3q&-272&      &            &      \\
    &   &   &-6q &\ddots& -qn(n+1) /2&      \\
    &   &   &    &      & -n^2-n^4   &      \\
    &   &   &    &      & -qn(n-1)/2 &\ddots\\     
    \end{bmatrix}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image: some band matrix]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) You might want to take a look at the [`nicematrix`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/nicematrix) package.

Answer (score 1):

Content of your matrix is not very clear (what is in the band?), so do you looking for something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
    \mathcal{L} = \begin{bmatrix}
 -2 &-3q&   &    &      &           &               &       \\
    &-20&-6q&    &      &           &               &       \\
    &-q &-90&-10q&      &           &               &       \\
    &   &-3q&-272&      &           &               &       \\
    &   &   &-6q &\dots &           &               &       \\
    &   &   &    &      & \ddots    &               &       \\
    &   &   &    &      &           & -qn(n+1)/2    &       \\
    &   &   &    &      &           & -n^2-n^4      &       \\
    &   &   &    &      &           & -qn(n-1)/2    &       \\
    &   &   &    &      &           &               &\ddots \\
    \end{bmatrix}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```